# Objects spawning in relation to resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to have objects spawn above the screen and then fall down. This is how I did it:

```
  public Canvas canvas;

 public GameObject prefab1;
 public GameObject prefab2;

 int minSpawnDistance = 50;
 int maxSpawnDistance = 550;

 private void Start()
 {
     StartCoroutine(SpawnPrefab());
 }

 IEnumerator SpawnPrefab()
 {
     while (true)
     {
         int chosenPrefab = Random.Range(0, 2);
         int chosenX = Random.Range(minSpawnDistance, maxSpawnDistance + 1);
         //this is just for randomizing the rotation
         Vector3 euler = transform.eulerAngles;
         euler.z = Random.Range(0f, 360f);
         transform.eulerAngles = euler;

         if (chosenPrefab == 0)
         {
             GameObject prefab = Instantiate(prefab1, new Vector2(chosenX, 1400), Quaternion.Euler(euler), canvas.transform);
         }
         else 
         {
             GameObject prefab = Instantiate(prefab2, new Vector2(chosenX, 1400), Quaternion.Euler(euler), canvas.transform);
         }


         yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
     }
 }
```

The issue arises when I change the Game View to fullscreen or just change the resolution of the game view. Then, the prefabs start spawning in the middle of the screen, because the canvas gets bigger. How do I make them always spawn above the canvas, regardless of how big it is? Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Fixed, used Screen.Width and Screen.Height, it works perfectly

```
public Canvas canvas;
public Camera mainCamera;

public GameObject prefab1;
public GameObject prefab2;
public GameObject mainMenu;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnPrefab());
}

IEnumerator SpawnPrefab()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int chosenPrefab = Random.Range(0, 2);
        int chosenX = Random.Range(0, Screen.width);
        int chosenY = Screen.height + Screen.height / 30;
        Vector2 spawnPos = new Vector2(chosenX, chosenY);

        Vector3 euler = transform.eulerAngles;
        euler.z = Random.Range(0f, 360f);
        transform.eulerAngles = euler;

        if (chosenPrefab == 0)
        {
            GameObject prefab = Instantiate(prefab1, spawnPos, Quaternion.Euler(euler), mainMenu.transform);
        }
        else 
        {
            GameObject prefab = Instantiate(prefab2, spawnPos, Quaternion.Euler(euler), mainMenu.transform);
        }


        yield return new WaitForSeconds(8f);
    }
}
```